# Replace Gulp task for uglify with npm script

Tags: npm, gulp

Currently I am using `npm` for package management and `Gulp` for running tasks. I am wondering if I am able to use npm scripts to *replace* gulp and use only npm.

My gulpfile.js for uglifying looks as following

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Minify JS
gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
 return gulp.src('js/agency.js')
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(header(banner, { pkg: pkg }))
 .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({
 stream: true
 }))
});
```

Is there a way to write a equivalent script in npm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I recommend you to have two directories `src` and `dist`.

- `src` contains **raw code** before any minifications made, it is used to read and edit your code.
- `dist` stands for *distribution* and contains **minified and concatenated** version of your code, it is used on production sites.

---

***Step 1***

You can use [uglify-js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to combine and minify your JavaScript files.

Install it with following command:
`npm install --save-dev uglify-js`

***Step 2***

In your **package.json** file set new task called ***uglify***:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "uglify": "mkdir -p dist/js && uglifyjs src/js/*.js -m -o dist/js/app.js && uglifyjs src/js/*.js -m -c -o dist/js/app.min.js"
}
```

---

**Explanation**

The first half of this task, `mkdir -p dist/js` creates a folder structure (`mkdir`), but only if it doesn't exist already (`-p` flag). Once that completes successfully, run the `uglifyjs` command. The `&&` lets you chain multiple commands together, running each one sequentially if the previous command completes successfully.

The second half of this task tells `uglifyjs` to start with all of the JS files (`*.js`) in `src/js/`, apply the "mangle" command (`-m` flag), and output the result to `dist/js/app.js`.

And to create a compressed version of `dist/js/app.js` we chain another `uglifyjs` command and passing the "compress" (`-c`) flag.

Comment: Also, found this [cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/9f10c555e32a8d06ddb0) for npm run-scripts